# How to update column value by adding "1" based on a condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, update

I have the following table `fields`:

```
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| field_id | form_id | form_section_id | is_required | grid_id | is_base_grid | field_type_id | field_seq |          field_name          | field_class | field_class_data |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   220481 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | NULL    | NULL         |             4 |        28 | Test                         | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281863 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | NULL    | NULL         |            10 |        29 | insert after yes no question | NULL        | NULL             |
|   220496 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 11      | 1            |             5 |        30 | test                         | NULL        | NULL             |
|   249234 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 12      | 1            |             5 |        32 |                              | NULL        | NULL             |
|   279877 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | NULL    | NULL         |             4 |        33 | Test Text Questions          | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281860 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | NULL    | NULL         |            10 |        34 | Something                    | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281914 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 23      | 1            |             5 |        35 | sssss                        | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281960 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 38      | 1            |             5 |        36 | yuyuyu                       | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 40      | 1            |             5 |        40 | ttttt                        | NULL        | NULL             |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

As you can see there are two `field_seq` with the same value `36` in this case.

Let's say I am inserting a new row just after `field_id=281960` and the `field_seq` for such new row is coming as `36`.

I need to build a query or even a stored procedure where I am able to find out if there is a row with `field_seq` equal or greater than `36` and if so then update the value of `field_seq` to the current value plus `1`.

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO `fields` VALUES(9999, 9926, NULL, 0, 41, 1, 5, 36, 'lllll', NULL, NULL);
```

Having this see possible cases below (with examples after each one):

**Case 1:** row with field_seq=36 exists on table already

- Keep the INSERT data as it's which will become the current `field_seq=36` new row
- Update the value of table row `field_seq=current+1` which will become `37`
- If there is a `37` already then repeat the previous step until there is no more repeated `field_seq`

Before:

```
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| field_id | form_id | form_section_id | is_required | grid_id | is_base_grid | field_type_id | field_seq | field_nanme | field_class | field_class_data |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|   281914 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      23 |            1 |             5 |        32 | sssss       | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      40 |            1 |             5 |        36 | ttttt       | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281960 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      38 |            1 |             5 |        37 | yuyuyu      | NULL        | NULL             |
|   281978 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      38 |            1 |             5 |        38 | vvvvv       | NULL        | NULL             |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+
```

After:

```
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
| field_id | form_id | form_section_id | is_required | grid_id | is_base_grid | field_type_id | field_seq |     field_nanme     | field_class | field_class_data |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   281914 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 23      | 1            |             5 |        32 | sssss               | NULL        | NULL             |
|     9999 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |    41   |   1          |             5 |        36 | lllll               | NULL        | NULL             | => new row inserted here
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 40      | 1            |             5 |        37 | ttttt               | NULL        | NULL             | => this was 36 now is updated to 37
|   281960 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 38      | 1            |             5 |        38 | yuyuyu              | NULL        | NULL             | => this was 37 now is updated to 38
|   281978 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | 38      | 1            |             5 |        39 | vvvvv               | NULL        | NULL             | => this was 38 now is updated to 39
|   220524 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 | NULL    | NULL         |             5 |        40 | Patient Information | NULL        | NULL             | => we don't care about this cause there is room for one more, if one insert makes the rows above become 40 then this needs to be updated to 41
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

**Case 2:** row with field_seq=36 exists on table already but next `field_seq` is greater than `37`

- Keep the INSERT data as it's which will become the current `field_seq=36` new row
- Update the value of table row `field_seq=current+1` which will become `37`
- In this case we do not need to continue updating since there is enough space to insert a few more rows before them become the same `field_seq`

Before:

```
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| field_id | form_id | form_section_id | is_required | grid_id | is_base_grid  | field_type_id | field_seq | field_name | field_class |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   281914 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      23 |             1 |             5 |        32 | sssss      | NULL        |
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      40 |             1 |             5 |        36 | ttttt      | NULL        |
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      40 |             1 |             5 |        40 | ooooo      | NULL        |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

After:

```
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| field_id | form_id | form_section_id | is_required | grid_id | is_base_grid  | field_type_id | field_seq | field_name | field_class |
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   281914 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      23 |             1 |             5 |        32 | sssss      | NULL        |
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      41 |             1 |             5 |        36 | lllll      | NULL        | => new row inserted here
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      40 |             1 |             5 |        37 | ttttt      | NULL        | => previous row with field_seq=36 was updated to 37
|   281972 |    9926 | NULL            |           0 |      40 |             1 |             5 |        40 | ooooo      | NULL        | => nothing happen to this one since there is room for more
+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1). How I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you _specifically_ looking for a value of `36` for inserted rows OR are you saying you want to check for an existing `field_seq` value that is greater than ANY incoming row due to an insert?  What if there is already a row with `field_seq` of `37` and a `36` is being inserted?  What if there are multiple rows being inserted into the table in one transaction?  I think more clarification on the criteria and desired results is needed.

Comment: I only see one record with field_seq equal to 36 in your first table.

Comment: @mathewb `36` is jut an example based on the preview data I provided it could be any value the rules I want to apply are the ones that should be matched no matter what the value of `field_seq` is. If there is a `field_seq=37` and `36` is being inserted then I should look for existent `36` in DB, if does not exists then `37` remains the same but if does exists then `37` becomes `38`, is that clear?

Comment: I suggested an edit to clarify your intent. Also, to further expand on what @ScottHodgin said - why didn't 40 get updated to 41 in your example? Do you only want to update if the insert/update creates a clash?

Comment: @mathewb I have explained the two possibles scenarios I am seeing here, let me know if that helps

Comment: Has `field_seq` any unique index on it?

Comment: @McNets I am not the DBA so I am not sure at all unless I can run a query to check if there is any unique index on such column

Comment: If there is any index on `field_seq` you need to use a CURSOR. It's important

Comment: You are developing a complex procedure against this table, you should have the `CREATE TABLE` statement and indexes available. Don't you? Please also add the version of SQL Server you use.

Comment: @McNets no I don't have any indexes on that column, ypercube thanks for the heads up

Comment: The question is much clearer now. Next question - what version of SQL Server are you working in?

Comment: @mathewb I have edited the OP again to reflect the two cases I am seeing here and added the SQL version as well, please check and let me know

Comment: The wanted results looks like a variation on UPSERT, except there is always an INSERT - plus UPDATEs when there is a conflict.

Comment: What happens if you try to insert seq=36 and exists seq=36 and seq=37 but it doesn't exists seq=38?

Comment: @McNets then the inserted `36` should remain as `36`, the current existent `36` should move into `37` and the `37` should move into `38`

Comment: Then the solution should try to find a gap into the next field_seq before to insert the new row, not only the next two records. It's more complicated. And slowly.

Comment: @McNets Yes, the idea is to keep the record coming as it's and move the rest of them by one if needed. It has to be based also in the `form_id` since the same sequence could exists for other forms (see comments on the answer below). I can provide you with the current SP I am running which has nothing about this so I need to place the solution within this SP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give this a try:

```
--enter procedure with insert parameters
DECLARE @field_seq INT = 36
DECLARE @field_seq_range INT

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM fields WHERE field_seq = @field_seq)
  BEGIN
    SELECT  @field_seq_range = MIN(f.field_seq)
    FROM    (
        SELECT  field_seq, LEAD(field_seq, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY field_seq) next_field_seq
        FROM    fields
    ) f
    WHERE   f.field_seq >= @field_seq
    AND f.field_seq + 1 < f.next_field_seq

    UPDATE  f
    SET f.field_seq = f.field_seq + 1
    FROM    fields f
    WHERE   f.field_seq BETWEEN @field_seq AND @field_seq_range
  END

--perform insert
```

The code is going to check to see if there is a collision on `field_seq.` If there is, it will scan the table to find the next gap, update all of the `field_seq` values in that range, and leave you a gap to insert the new record into. If no collision is found, the update is skipped. I can't make any guarantee on performance for this, though. I'm sure there are more optimal ways to do it.

Here's the [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2a72dd25ccc410e51c959ec43b1c30ed) - you can see the before and after the update occurs creating a gap for the insert to take place.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind you should add an error handler and use a TRANSACTION to be sure all affected records become updated.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T(field_id int, field_seq int);
>
> INSERT INTO T VALUES 
> (22156, 28),
> (22759, 29),
> (23458, 30),
> (28000, 31),
> (28101, 32),
> (29355, 33),
> (30000, 34),
> (30125, 35);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewID(@new_id int)
> AS
> BEGIN
>
>     DECLARE @field_seq int = 0,
>             @field_id int = 0;
>
>     -- try to find if there is some field_id > @new_id
>     SELECT   TOP 1 
>              @field_id = COALESCE(field_id, 0),
>              @field_seq = COALESCE(field_seq, 0)
>     FROM     T
>     WHERE    field_id > @new_id
>     ORDER BY field_id ASC;
>
>     -- if there isn't any field_id > @new_id
>     -- get MAX(field_seq) OR 1 in case there is no records
>     IF @field_seq = 0
>     BEGIN
>         SELECT @field_seq = COALESCE(MAX(field_seq), 0) + 1
>         FROM   T
>     END
>
>     IF @field_id > 0
>     BEGIN
>         UPDATE T
>         SET    field_seq = field_seq + 1
>         WHERE  field_id >= @field_id
>     END
>
>     INSERT INTO T (field_id, field_seq) VALUES (@new_id, @field_seq);
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

Insert a new record after `field_id=29355`

> ```
> EXEC InsertNewId @new_id = 29999;
>
> SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY field_id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> field_id | field_seq
> -------: | --------:
>    22156 |        28
>    22759 |        29
>    23458 |        30
>    28000 |        31
>    28101 |        32
>    29355 |        33
>    29999 |        34
>    30000 |        35
>    30125 |        36
> ```

Insert new record at end.

> ```
> EXEC InsertNewId @new_id = 31000;
>
> SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY field_id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> field_id | field_seq
> -------: | --------:
>    22156 |        28
>    22759 |        29
>    23458 |        30
>    28000 |        31
>    28101 |        32
>    29355 |        33
>    29999 |        34
>    30000 |        35
>    30125 |        36
>    31000 |        37
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=84017898fc0550f57a2aaf84c7610c38)*

Comment: Can you check the updated OP? Did your SP cover the 2nd case?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a subquery in your insert, something like....

```
INSERT INTO `fields` VALUES(9999, 9926, NULL, 0, 41, 1, 5, (SELECT MAX(field_seq) + 1 FROM fields), 'lllll', NULL, NULL);
```

might work

Comment: I think that the OP wants to update the contents of the table and keep the insert as it is. It should behave sort of like a linked list.